# Using Simple HTML Dom PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Ok i have a bit of a problem and hope someone can help me out.

I'm using Simple HTML Dom PHP Class and trying to grab info from another site example below.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");
$find_country = $html->find('div[class=inline] span', 0);
if (!empty($find_country)) {
    $country = $find_country->plaintext;
} else {
    $country = '';
}
```

Now on the site where this code gets the info from there are two that are the same example below

```
<div class="inline">
    <h3>Country:</h3>
    <span>USA</span>
</div>

<div class="inline">
    <h3>Run Time:</h3>
    <span>120 min</span>
</div>
```

Now i only want to grab the Country but some times the Country is not available and it ends up getting the run time so could i use

```
<h3>Country:</h3>
```

Part to stop this could someone please help me out thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="inline">
    <h3>Run Time:</h3>
    <span>120 min</span>
</div>

<div class="inline">
    <h3>Country:</h3>
    <span>USA</span>
</div>
EOF;

$doc = str_get_html($html);
```

Using simple you need to jump through some hoops

```
foreach($doc->find('h3') as $h3){
  if($h3->text() == 'Country:'){
    $country = $h3->next_sibling()->text();
    break;
  }
}
```

Using [advanced](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) you can get there with css:

```
$country = $doc->find('h3[text="Country:"] + span', 0)->text();
```